# Window default folder appears in different language

Tags: windows, file

This is a trivial but daunting question.

My Windows language is set to English. BUT the name of my desktop folder appears in Korean which causes multiple issues. (i.e. I cannot navigate thru the files in the terminal)

Here's the daunting part. The Desktop fold appears as English in some places, but when I view a specific folder's path (which is located in the Desktop), it still appears as Korean.

How do I fix this?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vista and later, all special folder names are always in English on the file-system and Desktop.ini files make the names localized in Explorer so this can't be your issue.

Looking at your screenshot we can see that the folder is inside OneDrive. This leads me to believe that you have turned on the [Important PC Folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-files-and-folders-in-onedrive-20d7bb65-425a-4209-9b71-4cad046cfdc8) OneDrive backup feature for your Desktop folder.

If you still need this backup feature then you need to try to rename the folder. [This page](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-onedrive-special-folders.html) recommends that you rename special OneDrive folders on the web-based OneDrive page. If you only want to rename it on one of your machines then you might have to edit the [user shell folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-redirect-user-shell-folders-to-a-specified-path-by-using-profile-maker-ed6289ae-1f9c-b874-4e8c-20d23ea65b2e) registry key.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after messing around the file system a bit. (I had the same exact problem)
Here is the steps I took:

- Go to the OneDrive page online and unlink your PC.
- Make sure to delete the OneDrive app too.
- Go to file explorer and locate C:\Users\USER_NAME
  On there you should see a shortcut named Desktop and a Folder named OneDrive with another Desktop shortcut and a few other things.
- Delete the Desktop shortcut in C:\Users\USER_NAME
- Ctrl + X everything in the OneDrive Folder, copy it to C:\Users\USER_NAME (this should give you the desktop back)

Now, for getting rid of the Korean file name:

- First, verify that the problem persists by checking any folder/file on your new desktop still has the Korean path (should be without the OneDrive now though)
- Go back to C:\Users\USER_NAME and right click the new Desktop shortcut.
- Go to the Location tab and change the name to 'Desktop'
- Click yes to the prompts and you're done!
  [Here is what mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WMnO.png)

[Don't have the before pictures, but this doesn't have OneDrive or the Korean anymore!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjpD.png)

SHORT ADDITION:
After you delete the OneDrive path and stuff, some default file locations will try to recreate your OneDrive folder. Changing the location like you did with the Desktop didn't work for me, so I just edited the registry.

- Go to: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
- Then anything like C:\Users\suhwa\OneDrive\Documents,
  change it to C:\Users\suhwa\Documents, and you should be set!

- Don't forget to backup the registry by File > Export > Save just in case :)